# C# non-LaTeX string equation into LaTeX string

Tags: c#, math, equation-solving

Is there something that can convert this

```
"(2+2)/2"
```

into this

```
"\frac{2+2}{2}"
```

I tried searching but I didnt find anything

Comment: Are you asking for occurrences of only and only ```(x+y)/z``` form or do you need this for all the equations in a text body? The first is trivial, the latter, not so much. Depending on the complexity of your expressions, you have to come up with an expression parser.

Comment: Of course for all equations

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.